# C# functions Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a function in file `Code.xaml.cs`.

```
public string send (string url)
{
//some code...
}
```

I want to call this function from another `.cs` file.

```
send("google.com");
```

But the debugger gives an error! How can I do this?

Comment: What is that error message exactly?

Comment: public static string send(..)... might help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever calling a dynamic method from a class, you will have to create an instance of that class.

```
class Test 
{
    public string send(string url) {}
}

class AnotherClass 
{
    public AnotherClass() 
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.send("google.com");
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can simply use the `static` keyword.

```
public static string send(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the send method isn't acting as a member function in the class that it's in, you can create a static Helper class.

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string send(string url)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in any other .cs file you can call:

```
Helpers.send("www.google.com")
```